# How to attach gameObject to referencePoint in Unity AR Foundation?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to anchor spawnpoints, where boats are being spawned, to fixed position. Because they are following camera movements, but they shouldnt.

I have tried to create `referencePoint` in script, it places the spawnPoints in correct place, but boats and `spawnPoints` still move along camera movements. And yes, I place both `spawnPoints` as children of `referencePoint`.

```
pos = cannon.transform.position; //same position and rotation as trackedImage
rot = cannon.transform.rotation;
Pose pose = new Pose(pos, rot);
refPoint = aRReferencePointManager.AddReferencePoint(pose);
refPoint.transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x - 2, pos.y + yValueChange, pos.z + 50);

foreach (Boat go in battleshipsGameScript.spawnedBoatList)//each boat added as child of refpoint
{
    //go.gameObject.transform.SetParent(refPoint.transform);
    //go.gameObject.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
}

battleshipsGameScript.spawnPoints[0].transform.SetParent(refPoint.transform);                
battleshipsGameScript.spawnPoints[1].transform.SetParent(refPoint.transform);
```

Also when I uncomment `go.gameobject` lines, the boats spawn in `0,0,0` position. The whole process starts to glitch.

Comment: I've never used unity AR, but it seems like you could just do `battleshipsGameScript.spawnPoints[0].transform.SetParent(null);` `battleshipsGameScript.spawnPoints[0].transform.position = new Vector3(pos.x-2, pos.y + yValueChange, pos.z + 50)`

Comment: Did you find any solution ?